# Multer Upload Speed Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

Currently, I am using Multer to handle file uploads for my application. I limit the file size to be less than 20MBs. When I am using localhost, a file size such as 77MB instantly throws me to the file too large error page that I have set up. However, when a file size of 77MB is uploaded in a deployment server, it takes considerably longer and crashes the application. Below is my code for the Multer setup. I am using express js. Does anyone know what's up with this or have a solution to fix this? Thanks!

```js
const upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: {fileSize: 20 * 1024 * 1024} }).single('file');
```

```js
router.post('/upload', upload, function (req, res, next) {
    // Stuff here
}
```

Comment: Have you used the [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) method?

Comment: @Tyler2P yes i have

Comment: And you're receiving an error..?

Comment: @Tyler2P yes the error handling is there. The error just occurs significantly slower when on deployment than localhost.

Comment: What multer storage are you using? And are you using a reverse proxy like Nginx in front of the app on deployment?

Comment: @MaximOrlov I temporarily store my files in a folder called uploads. I do not use a reverse proxy.

Comment: The reason why it might take longer to throw the error is that multer waits until it downloads the entire file before calculating file size, see https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/602. It's not efficient, I know. That would explain the speed difference. You said on localhost it throws an error but in deployment it crashes/shuts down the application which made me think the behaviour is different. However, from your comments it seems in deployment it throws the same way, just slower.

Comment: @MaximOrlov It crashes the application with file sizes such as 1GB which timeout the connection. However, with smaller sizes, it is significantly slower.

Comment: Yeah that's a downside of multer that it downloads the entire file even if it's above the size limit. I've heard people switching to formidable because of this. You might want to give that a try.

Comment: @MaximOrlov Okay, Ill give it a shot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MaximOrlov Just curious, what effects does a reverse proxy have on file upload speed?

Comment: @QiWang did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same...